# Mongodb c++ driver 3.0, not const arrays

Tags: c++, mongodb, c++11, bson

I am trying to create an array with the content of a vector

```
using bsoncxx::builder::stream;
auto doc = document{};
doc << "foo"
  << open_array;

for (auto i : v){
  doc << open_document << "bar" << i << close_document ;
}
doc << close_array;
```

I get the following error report:

```
error: no match for ‘operator<<’ (operand types are ‘bsoncxx::v0::builder::stream::document’ and ‘const bsoncxx::v0::builder::stream::open_document_type’)
       doc << open_document << "bar" << i << close_document ;
```

Any idea on how to do it?

Comment: You haven't shown a complete, compilable example, but, given a std::vector<int>{1, 2, 3}, what would you like the resulting BSON (expressed as JSON), to be?

Comment: {"foo": [{"bar":1}, {"bar":2}, {"bar":3}]}

Answer (score 2):

The C++11 bson driver is actually hiding a bit more complexity under the stream style api than it at first appears.

The problem you're encountering is that there is type information encoded into the expression on each successive '<<', so from your original example you'll need to:

```
auto sz = 100;

// Note that we capture the return value of open_array
auto arr = doc << "foo" << open_array;

for (int32_t i=0; i < sz; i++)
    arr << i;

arr << close_array;
```

This is because open_array creates a nested type that can accept values without keys, unlike doc, which needs key value pairs.

If you want something more inline, you can use the inline Callable facility as in:

```
auto sz = 100;
builder::stream::document doc;
doc << "foo" << open_array <<
    [&](array_context<> arr){
        for (int32_t i = 0; i < sz; i++)
            arr << i;
    } // Note that we don't invoke the lambda
<< close_array;
```

The callable facility works with things that take:

single_context - write one value in an array, or as the value part of a key value pair

key_context<> - write any number of key value pairs

array_context<> - write any number of values

See src/bsoncxx/test/bson_builder.cpp for more examples

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem with the streaming builder.

```
using bsoncxx::builder::stream;
auto doc = document{};
doc << "foo"
    << open_array
    << open_document
    << "bar1" << 1 
    << "bar2" << 5
    << close_document
    << close_array;
```

The above works, however if you want to do the following it doesn't work

```
doc << "foo"
    << open_array;
for (size_t i=0; i < sz; i++)
    doc << i;

doc << close_array;
```

I get the below error. The problem is that this behavior making using the stream builder is practically useless. Perhaps its a bug or the 10gen guys are not finished with the this part of the API.

```
doc << closerror: no match for ‘operator<<’ (operand types are ‘bsoncxx::v0::builder::stream::document’ and ‘const bsoncxx::v0::builder::stream::open_document_type’) doc << open_document << "bar" << i << close_document ;e_array;
```